# Calculating Average from input file?

Tags: c++, file, input

I need to calculate the average from a list of numbers given on a text file. I got it to work but for some reason it is adding the last number in the list twice and I cant figure out why.

Numbers in file are

```
34.8
33.5
32.9
30.5
33.3
31.9
30.6
34.4
36.2
35.2
33.2
31.0
31.8
34.4
33.0
32.9
32.8
31.9
31.6
32.2
29.5
36.8
30.9
30.2
35.3
32.1
31.2
36.0
38.2
34.2
34.5
34.7
33.2
39.4
31.2
28.6
```

Code:

```
double n;
double total=0;
double count=0;
double average=0;
ifstream input;
char name[13];

cout << "Enter a file name. "
    << "12 characters or less, please."
    << endl;
cin >> name;
input.open(name);
if(input.is_open())
{
    while(input.good())
    {
        do(!input.eof())
        {
            input>>n;
            total=total+n;
            count++;
        }
            average=total/count;
            cout<<"sum "<<total<<" count "<<count<<" average "<<average << endl; 

    }
    input.close();
}
else
{
    cout << "Error opening file\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Your C++ code looks like it was learned under the influence of C. Putting all the variable declarations at the beginning is an old C thing, and checking for EoF in the loop condition is a mistake in `<iostreams>` that's usually made by people more familiar with C, because in the C file API you do check for eof in the loop condition. In C++ this program should look more like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65f86daed376a2c3), which hopefully you can see is simpler and cleaner. I recommend looking for some 'modern C++' sources to supplement your education.

Answer (score 3):

You should have:

```
while(input >> n){
  total+=n;
  ++count;
}
```

instead of your do loop. The reason the last is added twice is because if `input >> n` fails (e.g. because of an EOF), n remains unchanged and you add it again.